# How to prevent one application clipboard text which reads by another app in background Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, clipboard, clipboardmanager

I am creating application with copy & paste functionality in Edittext. Which has some secure text, that needs to be prevent to read from clipboard by another application.
Is it possible to prevent our text to read from clipboard by other application that may run in background and listening clipboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry. The clipboard is world-readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Clipboard manager and add a listener to turn the clipboard blank everytime someone changes it. Here's how you do it:

```
            private ClipboardManager clipboardManager;
            private ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener clipChangeListener;

            clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager)ActivityName.this.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            clipChangeListener = new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                    clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText("", ""));
                }
            };
            clipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(clipChangeListener);
```

Be sure to remove the clipboard listener on `onPause` or `onDestroy`

```
if (clipboardManager != null && clipChangeListener != null) {
            clipboardManager.removePrimaryClipChangedListener(clipChangeListener);
        }
```